# Using utm parameters

Tags: url, utm

I am currently trying to use utm parameters and I was wondering if the order in which we use them have any importance into the url.
To say it into another way : 
Is 
http://example.com/blog-post-promotion-ultimate-guide?utm_source=site&utm_medium=320banner&utm_campaign=bpp

Same as :

http://example.com/blog-post-promotion-ultimate-guide?utm_medium=320banner&utm_source=site&utm_campaign=bpp

same as :

http://example.com/blog-post-promotion-ultimate-guide?utm_campaign=bpp&utm_medium=320banner&utm_source=site

?

Answer (score 0):

The order of UTM parameters does not matter. They are treated equally by Google Analytics and most other analytics tools.